# RowCommand GridView took 6,7 seconds

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I placed a GridView inside an update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
                runat="server">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView_Overview" OnRowCommand="GridView_Layout_RowCommand" />
</asp:GridView>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When the user press a button, the gridView will be filled up with a datatable:

```
GridView_Overview.DataSource = dataTable;
GridView_Overview.DataBind();
```

The dataTable contains more than 10000 records. Therefore, the binding process to the gridview took about 3,4 seconds.

When a row is selected in the gridview:

```
protected void GridView_Layout_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {if (e.CommandName.Equals("Select"))
      {
          int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
          GridViewRow row = this.GridView_Overview.Rows[index];
          Int64 pID = Int64.Parse(((Label)row.FindControl("ID")).Text); // abc
      }
 }
```

It took 5,6 seconds to perform GridView_Layout_RowCommand as above. What is the issue here? How can I improve the performance of selecting a row. If I discard the //abc code line then it is fast but then I can not get the ID value for further process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you implement paging on your gridview, I'm sure your binding process and event handler would be much faster.

Comment: Why are you passing in the index of the row in a command argument and then going off and finding the id why not just bind the id to the command argument.  Also your code does nothing.

Comment: @Shredder so, adding paging will be much faster?

Comment: @BenRobinson it is just for giving an idea at line //abc, it is slower. off course after finding the pID I will do more process. how to bind the it to the command argument? thanks in advance

Comment: The same way you bind it to the text box e.g. something like `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'`

Comment: @BenRobinson I tried it but it does not make any improvement if there are too many rows in the gridview. I mean instead of passing index in the argument, I got the ID but then the ID selection takes so long iwht too many data rows.

Comment: it is strange that even I selected the first row the RowCommand is quite slow...

Comment: @devn I am certainly Sure a client side MVC library like `BackboneJS`,`SpineJs` certainly lower the pain caused to server. Using client side paging & editing with restful webservice for updating i think is better in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is occurring because the asynchronous postback from the UpdatePanel will be triggered only after walking through the entire DOM.  If you're adding over 10000 records to the page then your DOM is going to be huge and the delay will be significant.

The key to solving your problem is destroying the GridView DOM elements before the postback is triggered.  This way, there will be much less DOM to be traversed.

See this blog post for some tips on handling the situation: [Slow performance of a GridView inside an UpdatePanel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/09/15/slow-performance-of-a-gridview-inside-an-updatepanel.aspx)

At the very least, including even the most basic form of paging will improve client-side performance as it will reduce the number of DOM elements added to the page.  For maximum results, you'll want to have a solution that also only selects each page of data so that you don't need to return 10000 records but only display a subset.

Answer (score 0):

Alison's answer mentions this, and I want to reinforce the point: you **really** should not display 10,000 records at a single time. Even with minimal HTML (which the `GridView` won't generate, because it's creating long server-side IDs), you've created a huge page for your users to download.

You've also created a lot of work for your server -- work that may be (is?) entirely unnecessary. How many of your users do you expect to go through all 10,000 records at once? That's asking a lot, even for extremely dedicated people.

The best way to increase performance and make your page more usable is to add paging. It's a little complicated, but paging will reduce the size of the data your server has to transfer, and significantly reduce the amount of time spent by the browser on the AJAX call and rendering the HTML.

MSDN has an overview up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx). Essentially, when the page changes, you'll want to do something like this (**note:** not exact code):

```
byte pageSize;

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    pageSize = 50;
}

void GridView_Overview_PageIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView_Overview.DataSource = dataTable.Skip(pageSize * e.NewPageIndex).Take(pageSize);
    GridView_Overview.DataBind();
}
```

You'll have to include a `using System.Data.Linq;` directive at the top of your code-behind page. You may want to let the user select the number of items per page, in which case you'd get `pageSize` from a control on the page, instead of setting it in `OnInit` as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Check what the client is sending back to the server using the development tools of the browser. What you should check specifically is the size of the post when clicking.

If my suspicions are right (can't imaging they've fixed it since I last tried and scrapped it) it's posting the entire viewstate back to the server and returning it again to keep the control state server-side intact which in your case with 10,000 row will be quite substantial.

The only way to limit the effect of this behaviour is to add paging and get the pages from the data source each time the user is shifting grid page i.e. don't bind the entire data set to the grid at once.